# How can I find the cross product of an inner sum and difference between two vectors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, euclidean-geometry, cross-product

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$. It is known that $A=B=3$. Find $\vec{E}=(\vec{A}+\vec{B})\times(\vec{A}-\vec{B})$

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&-18\hat{k}\\
2.&-9\hat{k}\\
3.&-\sqrt{3}\hat{k}\\
4.&3\sqrt{3}\hat{k}\\
5.&9\hat{k}\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted here was to try to decompose each vectors

$\vec{A}=\left \langle 3\cos 53^{\circ}, 3 \sin 53^{\circ} \right \rangle$

$\vec{B}=\vec{A}=\left \langle 3\cos (53^{\circ}+30^{\circ}), 3 \sin (53^{\circ}+30^{\circ}) \right \rangle$

But by attempting to use these relationships do seem to extend the algebra too much. Does it exist another way? some simplification?. Or could it be that am I overlooking something?

Can someone help me with this?.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. By expanding the cross product we find
$$(\vec{A}+\vec{B})\times(\vec{A}-\vec{B})=\vec{A}\times\vec{A}+\vec{B}\times\vec{A}-\vec{A}\times\vec{B}-\vec{B}\times\vec{B}.$$
Are you able to find each of the 4 cross-products on the right-hand side?

Recall the [algebraic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) of the cross product!

Comment: Responding to your original question. I'm unable to do it on my own. First off, from your equation, it is established that the cross product is conmutative. I was not aware of this. But how exactly can I simplify the equation which you have posted?. In other words, what do I do with $\vec{A} \times \vec{A}$ and with $\vec{B} \times \vec{B}$?. Can you further help me with this part please?. I'm lost. :(

Comment: No, the cross product is not commutative! I used the fact that it is distributive over addition. Please visit the link I gave you in my answer  about  the algebraic properties of the cross product. The first line says that $a\times a=0$!

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that the phrase was an actual link. I thought it was just highlighted. Yes as it is mentioned in the wiki entry the cross product of the same vector is zero. But what I tried to say was that the cross product is distributive. Then this is how you obtained that. In this specific method the fact of $37^{\circ}$ was unneeded. Or in general situation I dont need that angle?.

Comment: In general, in order to find $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}=-\vec{B}\times\vec{A}$, by definition of cross-product, you just need the angle between the vectors $A$ and $B$ (together with $|A|$ and $|B|$). Here you don't need the $37^{\circ}$ angle.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Any further doubt?

Comment: I was stuck with why was I given the $37^{\circ}$ and as I mentioned in the opening statement in my question I could use that angle to go with another route by decomposition of vectors but that would have expanded the algebra too much and that wasn't the right approach. What you said about that the only thing needed was the norm of each vector and the angle between both was just enough to solve this problem. But I'm wondering, can let's say $\vec{A}\times \vec{B} \times \vec{C}$ be calculated?, and why $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} \cdot \vec{C}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: For the first one, use the associative property $\vec{A}\times \vec{B}\times \vec{C}=(\vec{A}\times \vec{B}) \times \vec{C}=\vec{A}\times( \vec{B} \times \vec{C})$.  For the second one, note that $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}$ is a scalar not a vector so you can't multiply the result by the vector $\vec{C} $.

Comment: Interesting, but can you show a quick example of how would be calculated $\vec{A} \times \vec{B} \times \vec{C}$ using vectors i.e $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,0,-1)$? To me it doesn't seem to be much difference the insert of a bracket between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ and \vec{B} and $\vec{C}$.

Comment: Compute first $(\vec{A}\times \vec{B})$ and call it $\vec{u}$ then compute $\vec{u}\times \vec{C}$.  What do you get?

Comment: $(0,1,0) \times (1,1,1)=(1,0,-1)$ Then $(1,0,-1) \times (-1,0,-1)=(0,2,0)$ Am I right with this?.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $-9\vec k$. In fact, the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ has $30^\circ$ degrees. On the other hand\begin{align}\left(\vec A+\vec B\right)\times\left(\vec A-\vec B\right)&=\overbrace{\vec A\times\vec A}^{\phantom{0}=0}+\overbrace{\vec B\times\vec A}^{\phantom{-\vec A\times\vec B}=-\vec A\times\vec B}-\vec A\times\vec B-\overbrace{\vec B\times\vec B}^{\phantom{0}=0}\\&=-2\vec A\times\vec B.\end{align}The length of $\vec A\times\vec B$ is $3\times3\times\sin(30^\circ)=\frac92$, and therefore the answer is $-9\vec k$; in order to see why it is this and not $9\vec k$, use the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

Comment: I'm sorry. :( I'm still lost at this answer. The part where I'm stuck is at how to get from step one to step two. In other words why $\vec{A}+\vec{A}+\vec{B}\times\vec{A}-\vec{A}\times\vec{B}-\vec{B}\times\vec{B}=-2\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ why?! Can you explain to me this part?. The second part where you put the answer is by using the definition of the cross product. But exactly, how do I get the direction which is $\hat{k}$?.  Using the right hand rule?.

Comment: That's because given any two vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$, $\vec v\times\vec v=0$ and $\vec v\times\vec w=-\vec w\times\vec v$.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification!. But I propose you upgrade your last comment to be part of your answer because this identity I had forgotten and it was not too **obvious** to me. Mind doing that? :) The other thing where I'm still not sure is how did you get the sign for $\hat{k}$, does it come strictly from the scalar $-2$ in front of that product?. The angle $37^{\circ}$ was unneeded, or does it mean that in this specific method was not required?.

Comment: I've edited my answer. And, yes, the $37^\circ$ angle is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product is associative and anti-commutative.  (A+ B)X(A- B)= AXA- AXB+ BXA- BXB= -AXB- AXB= -2AXB.  Yes, since both A and B lie in the xy-plane -AXB is in the negative z direction.  And since $|AXB|= |A||B| sin(\theta)$, here |AXB|= 2(3)(3) sin(150)= 9. (A+ B)X(A- B)= -9k